# Does C-1602A-1YN LCD use the HD44780 controller?

Tags: lcd, buying, hd44780, compliance

I am new to using PIC microcontrollers and electronics in general. I have been reading a tutorial on how to interface a PIC with a HD44780 compliant LCD. As I have been shopping for a LCD I have been finding it difficult to tell whether a LCD uses the HD44780 interface after reading its datasheet. The specific device in question is the [C-1602A-1YN](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/1946068.pdf) from Tinsharp.  Please let me know whether this uses the interface, and where in the datasheet this information can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LCD uses (it's in the second page)

> Controller/driver: KS0066UP00CC/KS0065B

[KS0066](http://www.asix.cz/download/museum/pvk40/ks0066u.pdf) is Samsung equivalent of Hitachi HD44780.

Answer (score 0):

According to page two in the datasheet the controller is a KS66UP00CC which appears to more commonly be described as a KS0066U-00PCC. I've found quite a few references to it being HD44780 compatible for example from an [Old Arduino 4-bit LCD library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/LCD4BitLibrary#.UxZJJFfbc2g) page under the supported devices:

> Display 20x4 (KS0066U-00PCC et KS0065BPCC controllers, HD44780 code compatible)